How do I put a gradient on selected tab items in SwiftUI?
I cant get it to work to put a gradient on the images of tab items. Im working with SF Symbols.
I tried using Tabview{...}.tint(). This works for basic colors like .tint(.red). However it doesnt work for .tint(LinearGradient(colors: [.pink, .purple, .blue], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)).
Is there any way of applying a Gradient as an accent color or am I doing something wrong with the .tint()?
Also I am aware of creating images with the Gradients and then using an active and inactive image for when the certain tab item is selected, but that is just a ton of work for me.
This is how I have tried it, but the tab items just appear in a continuous color:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.gray
        
        
      }
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView {
            
            BrainView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image("brain")
                    Text("Brain")
                }
                .tag("Brain")
            
            FriendsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person.2")
                    Text("Friends")
                }
                .tag("Friends")
            
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "switch.2")
                    Text("Settings")
                }
                .tag("Settings")
            
        }
        .tint(LinearGradient(colors: [
            Color(red: 0.599, green: 0.535, blue: 0.74),
            Color(red: 0.724, green: 0.374, blue: 0.666)
        ], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        
        
    }
        
}


You could always use a custom tab bar, then you can style the tab items any way you like. See the answer to SwiftUi Change Tint of Unselected Item in Tab Bar for an example implementation.
